# Understanding bitwise evaluation of a bitmask in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to really wrap my head around this line of code:

```
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents
            forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

What's tripping me up is the bitwise |. How is it different from a normal || or OR?

Why use bitwise | vs. a logical ||?

(For reference, forState:UIControlStateSelected = 1 << 1; UIControlStateDisabled 1 << 2)

Comment: sorry for my stupid question, but... how beginner are you in software development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise `OR` is different from logical `OR` in that it performs `OR`s of individual bits, and does not short-circuit. In contrast, the logical `OR` always produces `1` or `0`, and it stops evaluating its arguments as soon as it is clear what answer it is going to get (i.e. as soon as it finds the first non-zero argument in the chain of its arguments).

Specifically for this case, `1 << 1` is binary `10`, and `1 << 2` is binary `100`, so `OR`-ing them together produces a binary `110`, or decimal `6`. If you were using the logical `OR` instead, you would simply get `1`, because the very first argument, `1 << 1`, is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

In short, a bitwise operation performs the logical operation on the single bits, whereas a logical operation works on the whole value.

In the case of masks, bitwise `OR` is used so you can compose multiple values in one.

For instance (using 16-bit integers)

```
0000000000000010 UIControlStateSelected 
0000000000000100 UIControlStateDisabled
-----------------------------------------------------
0000000000000110 UIControlState Disabled and Selected
```

A logical evaluation would instead return `true` since they are both non-zero